# Android tablelayout reducing the gap between two rows

Tags: android, android-layout

As shown in the image i want to reduce the gap between two rows (marked by red color) so that my edit text appears just below the text.

[image]

My code

> ```
> <TableRow
>     android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:padding="2dip" > 
>       <TextView
>           android:id="@+id/textView1"
>           android:text="@string/projectName"
>           android:textSize="16sp"
>           android:textAppearance="@string/projectName" 
>           android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>           
> </TableRow>
>
> <TableRow
>     android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:padding="2dip">        
>
>      <EditText
>          android:id="@+id/editText"
>          android:layout_width="0dp"
>          android:layout_height="35dp"
>          android:inputType="text"            
>          android:singleLine="true" 
>          android:background="@drawable/editbox_background_normal"
>          android:layout_weight="1"
>          android:padding="5dip"
>          />
>
> </TableRow>  
>       </TableLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all those paddings

```
   android:padding="2dip"
   android:padding="5dip"
```

You can use padding left and right instead.

 Try this

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 > 
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:text="@string/projectName"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textAppearance="@string/projectName" 
          android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>           
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="35dp"
         android:inputType="text"            
         android:singleLine="true" 
         android:background="@drawable/editbox_background_normal"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         />

</TableRow>  
      </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy try this,it must help you

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"> 
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:text="@string/projectName"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:textAppearance="@string/projectName" 
              android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>           
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp">        

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="35dp"
             android:inputType="text"            
             android:singleLine="true" 
             android:background="@drawable/editbox_background_normal"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:padding="5dip"
             />

    </TableRow>  
          </TableLayout>
```